# how do i create a java code that will accept a string and return the second character from the string?

Tags: java

For example if the function is given string ABCD, the function should return
the character B. I dont know nothing about coding, i'm a noob, any help
would be appreciated.Im using java eclipse

```
public class String {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num;
        do { 
            System.out.print(ABCD); 
            num = scan.nextInt();
            return myString.charAt (1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like you need to touch up on the basics, like how returns work and what void methods are

Comment: If you are really trying to learn, you should try some basic tutorials.

Comment: Start by reading documentation of String class. You should be able to find method `charAt`. Try using it. Come back if you will have problem with it. Post your real code and describe problems you are facing.

Comment: You need to define `String myString = "ABCD"` first, then use your `i` variable from scanner there `System.out.println(myString.charAt(i));`

Comment: void methods do not return anything

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String str = scan.nextLine();         // str="Shivam"
System.out.println(str.charAt(1));    // 'h'
```

You have to provide your input from the console, which is stored to the `String` variable str. The method charAt(i) gives the character at index `i`. `i` may be any index from 0 to the length of input string-1.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean this:

```
public static String get(String input, String where_to_split){
String[] s = input.split(where_to_split);
return s[0];
```

I will try to explane:
So basicly what i am doing is asking for an String [String input], the one where i only wants a few letters from. Them i am making a String array [String[] s =...] and i am setting it to split (split: splits the String into two arrays (will delete the letter [String where_to_split])) so if you want to return a a few letters you will need to put in for example:

```
get("Hello", "l");
```

So it will return:  s[0] = Hel and s[1] = o
But i coded that it only returns s[0] (The first array)

Answer (score -1):

Here is a complete code-snippet for what you want to do

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String test = "ABCD";
        System.out.println(getSecondLetter(test, 1));
    }

    public static char getSecondLetter(String s, int index)
    {
        return s.charAt(index);
    }
}
```

You should be able to run this.

Hope that helps!

Comment: OP need to accept the string from the user. ABCD was just an example.

Comment: You also shouldn't give out full code. I'm sure you're proud of this, but he will never learn anything if his attitude is "I've tried nothing and I'm all out of ideas". Then he learns that he can just put any homework here and someone will do it for him.